# CKEditor not working in Typo3 Backend Module

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x

I created a backend module using the Extension Builder.

The config file that's created looks (partial!) like this:

```
'body' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_thefield.body',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'enableRichtext' => true,
                'richtextConfiguration' => 'default',
                'fieldControl' => [
                    'fullScreenRichtext' => [
                        'disabled' => false,
                    ],
                ],
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],

        ],
```

According to the docs, it should be enough to have `enableRichtext => true`.

Alas, the Richtext-Editor doesn't show up on the form.

Any ideas? Did I forget to configure something? The CKEditor is configured in the user's backend-settings.

Fluid-static templates are included in TS-PageConfig.

Using T3 8.7

Comment: This TCA configuration part is correct. So the problem lies somewhere else. Could there be a typo in the rest of the tca file? Did you create an own yaml files for CKEditor? Do you have custom javascript in the backend? Do normal content elements show the CKEditor? Do you have in the SQL the body field configured as text?